# How to fix query with multiple joined tables?

Tags: sql, join, select

I have a main table M (Movies) and other tables L (Location), G (Genre), and S (Sub Genre).  Each of the "other" tables are in a one to many relationship to table M, using.

I want to list all the Blu Ray titles and pull in their Location, Length (Time), Comments, Genre, and Sub Genre.

My query is:

```
SELECT L.Location, M.Title, M.Length, M.Comments, G.Genre, S.SubGenre
FROM ((L
INNER JOIN M ON M.Location = L.ID)
INNER JOIN G ON M.Genre = G.ID)
INNER JOIN SubGenre ON M.SubGenre = SubGenre.ID
ORDER BY M.ID
WHERE M.Type is "BluRay"
ORDER BY M.ID;
```

It gives me a subset of what the subset (26) of what the total number of records should be (447.)

**1. Do I have the proper table relationships?**

**2. Do I really need the parentheses? (error without them)**

**3. How do I change my query to give me all the Location records, with the appropriate movie-related information?**

**4. What if I want to add additional tables?**

The DB schema:

[image]

Comment: What DBMS are you using. Those parentheses in the joins remind me of that horrible syntax in MS Access. Apart from this, the joins look fine. The first `ORDER BY` must be removed. `"BluRay"` should be `'BluRay'`, but some DBMS accept the double quotes. As to (3): You are already showing the locations. If you want to show locations that have no movies, then you need outer joins instead of inner joins. (4) That depends. Probably just more joins.

Comment: The best approach for writing SQL is to start small.  Write a query that produces the correct results using the minimum number of joined tables.  Then, once you have that, build on top of that by joining tables, as needed.  This will also help you write more focused questions on StackOverflow, which will help other users when they find your question in the future.  Hint: Keep in mind the difference between an inner join and a left join.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: The following code worked for my purposes:

SELECT 
            L.LocationName
        ,   M.Title
        ,   M.[Length]
        ,   M.Comments
        ,   G.GenreName
        ,   S.SubGenreName

FROM            Movies      M
    ((LEFT JOIN  Location    L   ON  L.LocationID    =   M.LocationID)
    LEFT JOIN  Genre       G   ON  G.GenreID       =   M.GenreID)
    LEFT JOIN  SubGenre    S   ON  S.SubGenreID    =   M.SubGenreID 

WHERE       M.[Type]    = 'BluRay'
ORDER BY    M.MovieID

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN on shared table columns.

For "How to change your query to give all Location records, with appropriate movie-related information" that depends on what you think is appropriate.

You should not need the parentheses. Unless you are using a SQL database I am not familiar with.

You do not need to put the INNER in because the default JOIN is INNER JOIN in all flavors of SQL databases. You also have 2 ORDER BY M.ID you only want the one after the WHERE.

I am not sure what you mean by more tables do you mean you tables to the JOIN or actually more tables?

Answer (score 0):

```
--  Note that Type and Length are in between square brackets, because those are reserved words.
--  Avoid use of reserved words with MovieType and MovieLength

SELECT 
            L.LocationName
        ,   M.Title
        ,   M.[Length]
        ,   M.Comments
        ,   G.GenreName
        ,   S.SubGenreName

FROM            Movies      M
    INNER JOIN  Location    L   ON  L.LocationID    =   M.LocationID
    INNER JOIN  Genre       G   ON  G.GenreID       =   M.GenreID
    INNER JOIN  SubGenre    S   ON  S.SubGenreID    =   M.SubGenreID 

WHERE       M.[Type]    = 'BluRay'
ORDER BY    M.MovieID
```